# Question about conditional independence

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am going through the presentation slides on this link:
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/10701_sp11/recitations/Recitation_4.pdf

On page 11, above chain rule, they have written the following distribution:

```
P(F,A,S,H,N) = P(F) P(F|A) P(S|F,A) P(H|S,F,A) P(N|S,F,A,H)
```

1. From where did they get this?  Especially `P(F|A)` - aren't they independent?
2. Why is it `P(H|S,F,A)` and not `P(H|S,F,A,N)` (like it is for the last term)?

Graph is here:

[image]

Comment: Second term  on the right hand side should be P(A/F) and not P(F/A).

Comment: @ZahavaKor, the site mentions *P(F|A)* - and I again have no idea why! :(

Comment: It's clearly a typo! It happens to the best of us... It has to be P(A/F)  to be mathematically correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's a general statement. Any joint distribution (likelihood or probability) can be written in term of a product of conditionals:

$$P(X_1, \ldots, X_n) = P(X_1) \cdot P(X_2 | X_1) \cdot \ldots \cdot P(X_n | X_{n-1}, \ldots, X_1)$$

Flu and allergy are not probabalistically independent because of Bayes Rule. They are causally independent though. If I know that someone has an allergy, then I can predict whether or not they have sinus (infection) and knowing this tells me something about the risk of flu since P(Flu | sinus) = p(sinus|flu) * p(flu)/p(sinus) and p(sinus) depends on allergy.

You get P(H|S,F,A) and don't condition whether or not there's a nose problem so you can obtain the correct marginal probability for headache problems. If both headache and nose condition on all 4 other variables, you will never be able to marginalize those likelihoods/probability models.

Comment: Could you please elaborate: *Flu and allergy are not probabalistically independent because of Bayes Rule*?  They don't have any connection between them, so shouldn't they be independent?

Comment: Also, if I understand your last paragraph correctly, then we do this just so that we can avoid a *deadlock*, wherein one depends on the other and vice versa, correct?

Comment: @user6490375 reread the argument about Bayes. No no concept of a deadlock at all. It may help you to remove the arrowheads, remembering Bayes rule.